# How to merge two arrays of undefined type in C# using .NET 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, merge

I'm trying to create a utility method that will accept two arrays as parameters, merge them together, and return the resulting array. Discarding duplicates.

Ideally, the parameters would accept any array type, such as int[] or string[].

I'm using C# .NET 1.1, and therefore do not have access to Generics or Array.Resize().

Is there a better way to merge two arrays, without knowing their type, but returning an array of the same type?

At this time, the following code returns an array of object[].  I'd like the returned array type to match the parameters.

```
public static object[] MergeArrays(object[] dest, object[] src)
{
    if (dest.GetType() != src.GetType())
        return null;    // The arrays are of different types

    if (dest.Equals(src))
        return dest;    // Don't merge with self

    // We now know there are two compatible and unique arrays
    int delta = src.Length;

    // Cycle through the passed materials and see if they already exist
    for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
        // Check to see if this material already exists
        for (int j = 0; j < dest.Length; j++)
            if (src[i] == dest[j])
            {
                // The material already exists, so we'll skip it
                src[i] = null;
                delta--;
                break;
            }

    // If there are still objects to merge, increase the array size
    if (delta > 0)
    {
        object[] = new object[dest.Length + delta];
        int index;

        // Copy the original array
        for (index = 0; index < dest.Length; index++)
            tmp[index] = dest[index];

        // Add the new elements
        for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
        {
            if (src[i] == null)
                continue;
            tmp[index++] = src[i];
        }
        dest = tmp;
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is all legal .NET 1.1:

```
public static object[] Merge(object[] first, object[] second) {
    if (first == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("first");
    }
    if (second == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("second");
    }
    Type firstType = first.GetType();
    Type secondType = second.GetType();
    if (firstType != secondType) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("type mismatch");
    }
    Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
    ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
    NewMethod(first, table, items);
    NewMethod(second, table, items);
    return (object[])items.ToArray(firstType.GetElementType());
}

static void NewMethod(object[] array, Hashtable table, ArrayList items) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
        object item = array[i];
        if (!table.Contains(item)) {
            table.Add(item, 1);
            items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm too lazy to find a good name for `NewMethod` so I just let Visual Studio default name it after an extract-to-method procedure.

Usage:

```
object[] a = new string[10];
object[] b = new string[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = i.ToString();
    b[i] = (i + 5).ToString();
}

object[] c = Merge(a, b);
Console.WriteLine(c.Length);
Console.WriteLine(c.GetType());
for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(c[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
15
System.String[]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Note that if you want to shove an array two `T[]` where `T : ValueType` into `Merge` you have to box the elements first and type the array as an `object[]`; this is because there is no conversion from `T[]` to `object[]` when `T : ValueType`. Moreover, because `GetType` is not virtual, the best that you can get out in this case is an `object[]`, not a `T[]`.

Comment: You're welcome; do you have a better name for `NewMethod`? I'm still thinking.

Comment: I normally would go with MergeCore or MergeInner

Comment: I actually went with MergeHelper, but MergeCore or MergeInner might be better. Overall, the solution looks elegant and seems to function well. Thanks again!